# Pass values from php from to the salesforce [PHP Integration]

Tags: apex, integration, php

I Have a generic PHP Application Form which has around 20 fields(say First Name,Last name,Mobile,Position etc ) .I am integrating this form to create a record in salesforce.

How can i pass the values entered in the form to the PHP  to create a record.

I am trying to create a record using Saleforce PHP tool kit.I have gone through the samples of the php code given by salesforce. But had no clue how to pass the parameters.

**PHP Code to create the record in salesforce**

```
<?php
$fields = array (`'First_Name__c' => 'Praveen','Last_Name__c' => 'Bonalu','Mobile__c' => '234-345-4567',);
$sObject = new SObject();
$sObject->fields = $fields;
$sObject->type = 'Candidate__c';
echo "**** Creating the following:\r\n";
$createResponse = $mySforceConnection->create(array($sObject));
print_r($createResponse);
```

?>

**Php form:to capture the date entered by the user**

```
FirstName: <input type="text" name="First name" value="<?php echo $name;?>">
```

`Last Name: <input type="text" name="Last name" value="<?php echo $Name;?>">`

```
Mobile: <input type="text" name="Mobile" value="<?php echo $Mobile;?>">
```

Thanks
Praveen

Answer (score 0):

In php $_POST is used to access any element value from any form so we will use that to access form elements values such as Firstname, Lastname, Mobile and others.

Html form

```
<form action="submit.php" method="post">
FirstName: <input type="text" name="Firstname" value="<?php echo $name;?>">
Last Name: <input type="text" name="Lastname" value="<?php echo $Name;?>">

Mobile: <input type="text" name="Mobile" value="<?php echo $Mobile;?>">
//and other fields here.
</form>
```

Submit.php

```
<?php
$fields = array ('First_Name__c' =>$_POST['Firstname'],'Last_Name__c' =>$_POST['Lastname'],'Mobile__c' => $_POST['Mobile']);
$sObject = new SObject();
$sObject->fields = $fields;
$sObject->type = 'Candidate__c';
echo "**** Creating the following:\r\n";
$createResponse = $mySforceConnection->create(array($sObject));
print_r($createResponse);

?>
```

I guess it will make sense now.

Comment: Hi Himanshu, I am getting this error when i made changes in the form [link]http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/100142/passing-the-values-to-the-php-salesforce-code

Comment: Its is giving me the error `Undefined index: Firstname in C:\xampp\htdocs\Salesforce\CandidateCreationPage.php on line 42

Notice: Undefined index: Lastname in C:\xampp\htdocs\Salesforce\CandidateCreationPage.php on line 43

Notice: Undefined index: Mobile in C:\xampp\htdocs\Salesforce\CandidateCreationPage.php on line 44`

Comment: that is correct error. reason being you are using $_POST on this page without submitting the page. $_POST is available only after submission of the form. it is better to move that whole code out of this creationPage.php and put in submit. php because you are using that in action method of form. that is the page where you are submitting the data.

Comment: @Himanshu--How can i pass the response(The record ID [SFDCID]) created using the php tool kit,to use it to upload a document to notes and attachments.

Comment: replied on your new question because posting of code was not possible here.